# C# decrypt Rijndael encrypted string using CakePHP's Security::rijndael

Tags: c#, php, cakephp, encryption, rijndael

I'm trying to decrypt a string encrypted using the Security::rijndael() function of CakePHP. Here's my code:

```
$enc = bin2hex( Security::rijndael( $field, Configure::read('Security.key'), 'encrypt' ) );
```

Please note that after encrypting, I'm using the bin2hex() function to convert it into a hex string that can be stored in the DB.

In CakePHP, I can easily decrypt this using:

```
$dec = Security::rijndael( hex2bin( $field ), Configure::read( 'Security.key' ), 'decrypt' );
```

I'm trying to achieve the same kind of decryption using C#, by running hex2bin first. I tried using a hex2bin() sample I found on the net:

```
private string hex2bin( string hexvalue ) {
    string binaryval = "";
    binaryval = Convert.ToString( Convert.ToInt64( hexvalue, 16 ), 2 );
    return binaryval;
}
```

...but this keeps returning an error: **Value was either too large or too small for a UInt64** and I cannot proceed beyond this point.

I'm looking for ideas on how to reverse the process in C#.

Thank you.

Comment: Rjindael is at least 128-bit, thus it is not safe to use `Convert.ToInt64` (64-bit), convert your `hexvalue` two by two to `byte[]` type

Comment: I realize this question is kind of old, but did you ever find a solution to this problem? I'm currently dealing with the same issue myself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to slice your string into a series of bytes that are decoded one at a time:

```
private byte[] hex2bin( string hexvalue )
{
    byte [] result = new byte[hexvalue.Length / 2];;

    for (int pos = 0; pos < hexvalue.Length; po+=2)
       byte[pos/2] =  Convert.Byte( hexvalue.SubString(pos, 2),  16 );

   return result;
}
```

And the result should be an array of bytes, not a string....